# I want to get only user id without text

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

I use some Laravel code,

```
$cid = $request->input('cusid');

$cus = DB::table('customers')->select('id')->where('cusid', $cid)->get();
```

code select customer "**id**" in cuctomers table referring "**cusid**".

As a result I got "**[{'id': 3}]**".
But I only want to get result as "**3**".

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]:1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":3}]' for column `teaapp2`.`daily_infos`.`customer_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `daily_infos` (`customer_id`, `numofkillo`, `advance`, `admin_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ([{"id":3}], 10, 10, 1, 2020-11-30 08:43:15, 2020-11-30 08:43:15))
```

How I would find it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this query only results in a single record from the DB, you can modify it to:

```php
$cus = DB::table('customers')->where('cusid', $cid)->pluck('id')->first();
```

Or

```php
$cus = DB::table('customers')->where('cusid', $cid)->first()->id;
```

Or if you have a `Customer` model:

```php
$cus = Customer::where('cusid', $cid)->first()->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to call `value('id')`, like:

```
DB::table('customers')->where('cusid', $cid)->value('id');
```

The query builder will automatically select only the `id` column. Also, try to use eloquent models instead of querying tables directly.